# Forwarding Traffic from TUN interface to XX

Tags: linux, tunneling, ip-forwarding, tun

**My setup is the following:** I'm writing a program that creates a **tun** interface and writes raw (Layer 3) packets to that interface. For example a ICMP ping packet (to make things easy).

Now i want to redirect those packets from the tun interface to my eth interface. I already tried the typical FORWARD iptables rules and also the option ip_forward is set to 1.

I can see the valid ICMP packets in wireshark for the tun interface, but the redirection won't work and nothing appears for the eth interface in wireshark. The ping is directed to an outside service (e.g. 8.8.8.8).

I guess that i'm missing one crucial thing on why this is not working, but cannot see it...

*Info:* I already searched for all "Forward Tun to XX" posts, but i haven't found a solution that actually worked.

**Edit:**

Iptable rules:

```
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -t nat -F
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o wlp4s0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.1/24 -o wlp4s0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.2.73
```

i tried it with `SNAT` and the following MASQUARADE rule as well:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.1/24 -o wlp4s0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Both unsuccessfull.

Output of `ip addr`:

```
46: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none
    inet 10.0.0.1/24 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1218:6be2:934b:355b/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Output of `ip route`

```
10.0.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1
```

And `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Comment: Please show us `ip addr`, `ip route`, `iptables-save` output. Also, just to be sure, `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`.

Comment: Edited the post

Comment: No, I meant, we need a **complete** outputs of these commands. You may mask out sensitive data (but not remove any single line); it's unlikely there will be anything sensitive; private IPs (RFC1918) **are not** sensetive per se, so better left them as is.